# What is distributed caching?

Tags: caching, distributed-caching

Can I define "Distributed Caching" like one of the possible configurations resulting of the combination between caching and clustering ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, here the term "distributed" comes from [Distributed Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing) where as "caching" is the [technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29) used to exploit the locality(both temporal and spacial) of data when entertaining memory requests. Traditional idea of memory caches is combined with distributed computing architecture in order to provide high performance, availability and scalability to the applications that use caches.

Once the caching mechanism is distributed we can refer it as "distributed caching". This distribution is a more general term that the cache can be distributed over a distant network or within a different nodes of a single computing base.

The most common application is to set up a separate cache cluster in order to distribute the load of cache queries among different nodes.

Reference:

1. [Cache Topologies](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/cache-topologies)
2. [Distributed Caching On The Path To Scalability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942840.aspx)
3. [Caching in the Distributed Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd129907.aspx)